# Prevent SQL File From Running As a Script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tens of SQL files that contain individual queries and update commands. These commands are intended to be used as a starting point for manual updates to the database, they are not structured to be ran as scripts.

Is there an SQL command I can place at the start of these files to stop an inadvertent click of the 'Run Script' button? Return, halt, stop?

I'm opening these in Oracle's SQL Developer, and the 'Run Command' and 'Run Script' buttons are right next to each other...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `exit` command at the top of your script.

If someone accidentally runs it as a script, it will immediately disconnect and will not run the rest of the statements.

Example:

```
exit

update t set a = 'abc';

drop table t;

...
```

Comment: Is there a solution that works across different SQL implementations? exit doesn't seem to work in MS SQL, yet it does highlight as blue.